# Specify a sender port

Tags: aeron

I'm guessing that there is a way to specify a port for Aeron to use when sending data over, but I can't find it.

Let's say for example that Machine A has a publication to 2.2.2.2:12345.
Machine B has a corresponding subscription and it works fine.

However, the source port coming from A is chosen at random. How can I specify the source port that the sender should use ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the control address on the Channel URI for the publication, e.g. `aeron:udp?endpoint=2.2.2.2:12345|control=2.2.2.1:12346`.  In this example `2.2.2.1` is the address of the server running the publication.